# Bootstrap carousel not working with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to use bootstrap carousel along with angular js to display images in carousel content.
But, when the navigation links clicked, it displays blank page.

My code sample is as follows. (**Note** : This code works well only with **Bootstrap 3.1.0** but not along with **AngularJS 1.2.13**)

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/c.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/b.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/a.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: did you remember to include jquery before bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes. I have added it before bootstrap.js.

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle or plnkr to demo this problem?

Comment: Following link is my demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/IVw6tSxi0VjhT2ppnaDZ?p=preview                                                                                                    **Source** : I have used the demo code from the link http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating & modified it

Comment: they're really asking a lot I think, when you have to jump through hoops like this just to use a Bootstrap component which JUST WORKS everywhere else.

Answer (score 71):

Building on what rbanning said, instead of adding the event handler you can just, after replacing the anchor tags with span tags, replace the href attribute with a "data-target" attribute and bootstrap takes care of the rest.

Like so:

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/c.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/b.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/a.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
<span class="left carousel-control" data-target="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</span>
<span class="right carousel-control" data-target="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working for me as i m calling the function also $('#carousel').carousel('next');
while hitting next please help

Comment: It is working for BUT i think you forgot the '#' in <li> data-target property.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned, the issue is with AngularJS and ngRoute intercepting the a-link clicks.  I had this problem but did not want to use Angular UI Bootstrap (as described in other answers).

So, I changed the .carousel-control elements from links (**a** tags) to spans.

```
<span class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</span>
<span class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</span>
```

Then, I added an event handler as follows...

```
  $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000,
                pause: "hover",
                wrap: true
            })
            .on('click', '.carousel-control', handle_nav);

  var handle_nav = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nav = $(this);
        nav.parents('.carousel').carousel(nav.data('slide'));
  }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: great job, helped me and I have been trying to fix this for hours!

Comment: helped me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Its not working for me i dont know how it is working for u guys,

Answer (score 8):

Set `target="_self"` in your carousel controls:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev" target="_self">
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to bind your carousel, you can solve this by adding a top level element with  `ng-non-bindable` directive:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- carousel content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also just use ng-click on both controls.

I'm using this on my site (note `href=""` is blank now)

In view:

```
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="" ng-click="slide('prev')" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" ng-click="slide('next')" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.slide = function (dir) {
    $('#carouselId').carousel(dir);
};
```

Comment: This example is most likely to work in recent versions of angular and bootstrap. I have tested with version 1.4.9 and 3.3.6 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

No any problem in the code you showed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1vq7DUXegQdBq3jvj7Zy?p=preview

Comment: he is explaining that his code does not work with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Angular UI to get Bootstrap and Angular to play along nicely ?

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

EDIT:

Your code isn't working because on the navigation links you have href attributes set at #Carousel. So when you click on those links Angular router will try to change view and to display the one called Carousel which isn't defined in your $routeProvider hence the blank page.

Since you're using Bootstrap.js it seems like you absolutely need these href attributes so maybe get rid of the router. Or give a try to Angular UI ;)

Comment: Can you just visit the demo link mentioned above & help me in fixing the problem?

Comment: I have used Angular UI to fix this issue. But it seems to be not working yet. Here is the [plunkerDemo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zwWfCGVBbQ4ej2JJ6dlq?p=preview)

Comment: I only see an `<accordion>` element on your contact view, I though you wanted a carousel?

Comment: I was looking for all the bootstrap elements like carousel/accordion/etc work with angular js. Now I got this working. [plunkerLink](http://plnkr.co/edit/EkZ8LmNx1mPwkIjnnSwF?p=preview)

Comment: Ok great ! I've added a `<carousel>` in the about page for completeness sake (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uXIpRbhBwVsDyfB8iV3u)), no more issues?

Answer (score 0):

This works, without modify the original bootstrap example

```
$("a.carousel-control").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().carousel($(this).data("slide"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make function and place it on prev/next arrow in html.

```
$scope.prevSlide = function() {
    $('#MY-CAROUSEL-ID').carousel('prev');
};
```